# grep count of a string with a filter condition

Tags: bash

I need to do a grep count of a string with a filter condition .

The context is

Data will be genearetd in the below format in our log files

```
2013-05-17 10:06:40,693[qtp1957835280-12 Selector1] ERROR(CustomThread.java:<disconnect>:202)- onDisconnect: CustomThread [customerId=122, formattedId=testuser] reason : 1004, reasonMessage : closed
```

The log file is having data of all the previous days also (ie 17 , 16 , 15 , 14 , 13)

But i want to find the count of reason : 1004  for the present day that is 2013-05-17

If i execute `grep -c 1004 application.log`  its giving me the count of the previous daya also

Please let me know is it possible to get the count of 1004 for the current day only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 grep -c '^2013-05-17.*reason : 1004' file
```

Comment: I would add `reason : ` into the pattern. unless you are sure there is no other 1004. (customerId?, qtpstring?...)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
grep `date +%Y-%m-%d` file | grep -c 1004
```